# Traceback error virt-manager : 'module' object has no attribute 'SSL_ST_INIT'

Tags: 16.04, python, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I'm not able to run virt-manager or virt-install on Ubuntu 16.04. Every time I try it a python error occur :

```
➜  / $ virt-manager                      
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virt-manager", line 34, in <module>
    from virtinst import util as util
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/__init__.py", line 87, in <module>
    from virtinst.distroinstaller import DistroInstaller
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/distroinstaller.py", line 26, in <module>
    from . import urlfetcher
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/urlfetcher.py", line 27, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
    from .packages.urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 54, in <module>
    import OpenSSL.SSL
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import rand, crypto, SSL
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 118, in <module>
    SSL_ST_INIT = _lib.SSL_ST_INIT
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SSL_ST_INIT'
```

--

```
➜  / $ virt-install                      
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virt-install", line 28, in <module>
    import virtinst
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/__init__.py", line 87, in <module>
    from virtinst.distroinstaller import DistroInstaller
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/distroinstaller.py", line 26, in <module>
    from . import urlfetcher
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/urlfetcher.py", line 27, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
    from .packages.urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 54, in <module>
    import OpenSSL.SSL
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import rand, crypto, SSL
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 118, in <module>
    SSL_ST_INIT = _lib.SSL_ST_INIT
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SSL_ST_INIT'
```

Can you help me ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix it :

```
sudo apt-get --auto-remove --yes remove python-openssl
sudo pip install --user --upgrade cryptography
sudo pip install pyOpenSSL
```

I hope that will help people !